# Cut in excel doesn't work, and copying tables from one program to another returns text

Tags: microsoft-excel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does cutting a cell in Excel not work properly?](https://superuser.com/questions/405180/why-does-cutting-a-cell-in-excel-not-work-properly)

My excel 2007 on Windows 7 operating system seems to have a probelm with regular cut function. when I highlight cells I want to cut and press cut (either on keyboard shortcut Ctrl+x, Home menu cut command, or from the right-click menu) cells start flashing for a split second and after that they only turn normal. When I want to paste them, they past as if copy function was used. If I try to rightclick to use function "insert cut cells" it is not one of the offered options at all.

On my home computer I have same combination, Excel 2007 on windows 7 and it works just fine. COuld the problem be due to 64-bit win7 version at my job, and 32-bit version at home?

Another problem is when I copy table from excel to word, in word pasting results in unformatted text instead of table as it was in excel.
Did someone have such problems and can offer a solution?
Thanx a lot.

Comment: With reference to your first problem, are you sure that the sheet is not protected or that the spreadsheet has not been opened "read-only"?

Comment: No. Sheet is unprotected. It is the same on all the documents in excel I have tried to edit. They work on myhome comp, and on this one they cut doesn't work.

Comment: Have you done a sweep for macro viruses recently?  Some of them play in and around the clipboard and could easily produce unexpected behavior like what you are describing.

Comment: This is usually the beginning of a huge question-answer comment flow, but: does cut/paste work in totally different software? (ie: mail) Do you have any software that overrides key strokes? (ie: SharpKey) Did you check for sticky keys? Do you have by chance VirtualBox installed? (it sometimes screws the Host machine keyboard). Pasting text is usually Ctrl+Shift+V instead of Ctrl+V, so I would check sticky Shift first.

Comment: I use only MS software, cut/paste works as usual in Word and Outlook. I have just tried it. But pasting tables is problem in every osftware I use. In word, outlook, IE, when I paste table instead of a table I get plain text. (except when I move table with control pressed).

Answer (score 1):

https://superuser.com/a/405393/128522

I later found similar question, and answers to it solved my problems. THe problem was caused by Skype click-to-call program, and after uninstalling it everything worked completely normally.